# AngularStrap hover popover

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I am trying to make the appearance of popover when hover the button.

Example code:

```
<button data-content="some data with links" data-auto-close="1" data-placement="bottom" bs-popover html='true' data-trigger="hover">Popover</button>
```

The popover does appear when I hover the button. But the problem is when I mouse move to the popover, it disappear. How can I have the popover to stay appear when I move to it? How can I have the popover hide when I click on the content link on it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WojtekKruszewski/Zf3m7/22/) for the exact same thing. Hope it helps.

HTML:

```
<p id='container'>
<button class='btn btn-primary btn-large' data-popover="true" data-html=true data-content="<a href='http://www.wojt.eu' target='blank' >click me, I'll try not to disappear</a>">hover here</button>
</p>
```

JS:

```
var originalLeave = $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.leave;
$.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.leave = function(obj){
  var self = obj instanceof this.constructor ?
    obj : $(obj.currentTarget)[this.type](this.getDelegateOptions()).data('bs.' + this.type)
  var container, timeout;

  originalLeave.call(this, obj);

  if(obj.currentTarget) {
    container = $(obj.currentTarget).siblings('.popover')
    timeout = self.timeout;
    container.one('mouseenter', function(){
      //We entered the actual popover – call off the dogs
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      //Let's monitor popover content instead
      container.one('mouseleave', function(){
        $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.leave.call(self, self);
      });
    })
  }
};


$('body').popover({ selector: '[data-popover]', trigger: 'click hover', placement: 'auto', delay: {show: 50, hide: 400}});
```

Comment: The question is for AngularStrap. Not Bootstrap.